# Centos 6.4 in VirtualBox fail to start eth0

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

Two interface files are in */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts*,
ifcfg-eth0 file:

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=08:00:27:DA:52:FB
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=...
ONBOOT=yes
MM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

ifcfg-eth1 file:

```
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=08:00:27:B1:7B:AA
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=...
ONBOOT=yes
MM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.57.101
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

`ifconfig` only gives eth1 and lo, but not eth0.

`service network status` gives:

```
Configured devices:
lo eth0 eth1
Currently active devices:
lo eth1
```

`ifconfig eth0 up` gives:

```
eth0:unknown interface: No such device.
```

Centos running in Virtualbox, configured with two NIC. One is using NAT, the other is HOST-ONLY. How could I bring up eth0 so it could use Internet?

[image]

EDIT: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` shows eth2, which should be eth0. Fix it, and reboot, eth2 again.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kernel version, check for eth0 in the /etc/modprobe.conf (kernel 2.6) or/etc/modules.conf (kernel 2.4). If it's not there, find out what module does you NIC need. Add the module with modprobe, check if it's loaded, recheck with ifconfig if it's working and if all goes well, make the change stick after reboot (write the addition to etc/modprobe.conf).

Alternately, change the NIC type Virtualbox to something else like e1000 .

Comment: The /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules  says eth0 as eth2. But in service network status and in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 says the device is eth0. Why so odd?

Comment: Due to Virtualbox configuration modifications. Probably eth0 was the old initial config and it became eth2 after altering the config.

Comment: I installed a clean iso as a comparison, everything is configured by "next". It has only one interface, and eth0 works fine.

Comment: Try to configure the clean one just like the config with problems and see what occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The mac address in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules is different from that in ifcfg-eth0. Change the MAC address in ifcfg-eth0 the same as that in 70-persistent-net.rules. and reboot the system or service network restart.

Comment: or don't set the MAC at OS level but on the vNIC in VirtualBox :)

Comment: @Zina how to do that (set MAC on the vNIC)?

Comment: You can change it in the settings of the VM, Network Tab, Advanced, MAC Address - [see here](http://imgur.com/a/tkXEK)